# how to release the postgresql table space smoothly

Tags: postgresql

I am using this command to release PostgreSQL 13 table space right now:

```
 VACUUM FULL VERBOSE sentence;
```

but this operation will lock the table, any better way to release table space?

Comment: https://reorg.github.io/pg_repack/

Comment: Alternatively, try pg_squeeze.